# Python elif mistake

Tags: python

```
def make_url_query_string(params):
    return '?' + '&'.join([str(key) + '=' + str(params[key]) for key in params])

def check_updates(limit=5):

global offset
        params = make_url_query_string({'offset': offset+1, 'limit': limit, 'timeout': 0})
        request = requests.get(URL + TOKEN + '/getUpdates' + params) # Отправка запроса обновлений
        if not request.status_code == 200: return False 
        if not request.json()['ok']: return False 
        if not request.json()['result']: return False 
        for update in request.json()['result']: 
            offset = update['update_id'] 
            from_id = update['message']['from']['id']
            message = update['message']
            if 'text' in message:
                print '>> OFFSET: ', offset
                print '>> MESSAGE:', message
                print '-' * 10
            else:
                continue
            if message == '/help':
                send_respond ('/help message', from_id)
            elif message  == '/start':
                send_respond ('/help - Show available commands list', from_id)
            elif message == u'привет':
                send_respond ('Приветствую!', from_id)
            elif message == u'hello':
                send_respond ('Hey there!', from_id)
            elif message == 'как дела?':
                send_respond ('Нормально, как твои?', from_id)
            else:
                send_respond ('I don\'t understand that yet!', from_id)
```

The problem is that the bot answer "I don't understand that yet!" on any message, even /help and other that are in the code. How can i fix dat?

Comment: Provide more insights

Comment: Have you checked what `message` is being evaluated as by printing it?

Comment: Ideally, `print(repr(message))` to show you any e.g. whitespace unambiguously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing your array to a string. This will never result in anything. You might want to get the message's text instead.
You can try to do this in a following way:

Change these lines:

```
 else:
        continue
 if message == '/help':
```

To these:

```
 else:
        continue
 message = message['text']
 if message == '/help':
```

Answer (score 2):

messages containing `'/help'` or `'/start'` does not containt `'text'` thus they trigger evaluation of the else clause of your `if 'text' in message`, skipping the whole tests for `send_respond`.

Only message containing `'text'` can evaluate these test and naturally only the `else` match in these cases.

Comment: The directive of 'text' in message is in fact a check for the field 'text' being present in the message dictionary.

Comment: Oh yeah, missed the `from_id = …` line. But in any case, either message is a string containing `'text'` and not matching the elif, or it is a dictionnary and is not equal to a string.

Comment: Nope. Python treats the ```in``` operand for strings and dictionaries differently. So the user's code: ```if 'text' in message:  ... else: continue ``` actually checks if there is a field called 'text' in the message dict, and if there isn't, it just skips the loop iteration and goes to the next message dict. It has nothing to do with the message text itself.